# How can I join insurance policies by a non-unique ID?

Tags: sql, hive

I am doing a request in hive. I have a task to join two tables with insurance policies in two weeks from createdate. I have a nonunique key personno (ID of a person), it has more than one record on one ID and createdate (a date of creating an insurance policy). I also have a column applicationno, which is an index from (1 to N) of created insurance policies, which we can say it's unique for all policies. I also have columns like insurance sum. I need to join Table1 to Table2. Table 1 is longer than Table 2.

TABLE 1

| personno | createdate | applicationnno | insurancesum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.03.2023 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 3 | 200 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 4 | 300 |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 5 | 250 |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 6 | 150 |

TABLE 2

| personno | createdate | applicationnno | insurancesum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.03.2023 | 7 | 100 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 8 | 200 |
| 2 | 03.03.2023 | 9 | 150 |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 10 | 150 |

To get something like these, the desired result is

| personno | createdate1 | applicationnno1 | insurancesum1 | createdate2 | applicationnno2 | insurancesum2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.03.2023 | 1 | 100 | 01.03.2023 | 7 | 100 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 2 | 200 | 02.03.2023 | 8 | 200 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 3 | 200 | 03.03.2023 | 9 | 150 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 4 | 300 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 5 | 250 | 03.03.2023 | 10 | 150 |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 6 | 150 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I wrote a request like this

```
SELECT 
a.personno, 
a.createdate,
a.applicationno,
a.insurancesum,
b.applicationno,
b.insurancesum
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
ON a.personno=b.personno
WHERE a.createdate Between cast(b.createdate as date)
AND DATE_ADD(cast(b.createdate as date),14);
```

Instead of my desired result I get something like duplicate answers in case of many rows on one date on same ID.

| personno | createdate1 | applicationnno1 | insurancesum1 | createdate2 | applicationnno2 | insurancesum2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.03.2023 | 1 | 100 | 01.03.2023 | 7 | 100 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 2 | 200 | 02.03.2023 | 8 | 200 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 3 | 200 | 03.03.2023 | 9 | 150 |
| 2 | 02.03.2023 | 4 | 300 | 03.03.2023 | 9 | 150 |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 5 | 250 | 03.03.2023 | 10 | 150 |
| 3 | 03.03.2023 | 6 | 150 | 03.03.2023 | 10 | 150 |

Help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
a.personno, 
a.createdate,
a.applicationno,
a.insurancesum,
b.applicationno,
b.insurancesum
FROM (select TABLE1.*
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONNO ORDER BY APPLICATIONNO) AS 
RN1 from TABLE1) a
LEFT JOIN (select TABLE2.*
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONNO ORDER BY APPLICATIONNO) AS 
RN2 from TABLE2) b
ON a.personno=b.personno
AND a.rn1 = b.rn2
WHERE a.createdate Between cast(b.createdate as date)
AND DATE_ADD(cast(b.createdate as date),14);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

your current query is due to the duplicate row in the result set. You can use window functions to assign row numbers for each row within the same personno and createdate group in both tbles. you can then do an FULL JOIN on these row numbered subqueries.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.personno,
    a.createdate AS createdate1,
    a.applicationnno AS applicationnno1,
    a.insurancesum AS insurancesum1,
    b.createdate AS createdate2,
    b.applicationnno AS applicationnno2,
    b.insurancesum AS insurancesum2
FROM
    (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personno, createdate ORDER BY applicationnno) AS rn
      FROM TABLE1) a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personno, createdate ORDER BY applicationnno) AS rn
      FROM TABLE2) b
ON
    a.personno = b.personno
    AND a.rn = b.rn
WHERE
    a.createdate BETWEEN b.createdate AND DATE_ADD(b.createdate, 14)
```

the subqueries within the main query assign a row numberr to each row within the same person and createdate partition, ordered by the applicationnno. This will hellp in pairing corresponding plicies based on the same order of creation. Then the main query then join the modified subqueries on personno and rn, and filters the results based on the daate range condition. This ensures that only the policies within a 14 days window are matched.